# MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

All of a sudden I keep getting a `MetadataException` on instantiating my generated `ObjectContext` class. The connection string in App.Config looks correct - hasn't changed since last it worked - and I've tried regenerating a new model (edmx-file) from the underlying database with no change.

Anyone have any ideas?

Further details: I haven't changed any properties, I haven't changed the name of any output assemblies, I haven't tried to embed the EDMX in the assembly. I've merely waited 10 hours from leaving work until I got back. And then it wasn't working anymore.

I've tried recreating the EDMX. I've tried recreating the project. I've even tried recreating the database, from scratch. No luck, whatsoever.

Comment: If an question SO about a specific product that has over 200k views, then the product is not functioning the way users are expecting. I would like to see Microsoft address this. Here's a link to give them suggestions if you have time: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio.

Comment: My problem solved, by replacing connection-string copied from db-layer project.

Comment: I also face this issue, I just clean and rebuild solution which works fine.

Comment: The Marquis de Sade is alive & well, and works at Microsoft. This really is Entity Framework hell.

Comment: See the comment under the accepted answer. In the end it was nothing but an incorrect connection string.

Comment: I had the same error (and lots of hanging) seemingly _"out of the blue"_ using VS2022. I restarted PC. Compared and checked the EDMX connection string/settings as per @Craig Stuntz (one of the answers below) and other we.config settings - still no dice. I started VS2022 in SAFE MODE: `devenv /SafeMode`, the solution wouldn't run (not all projects loaded - reasons provided in 'output') - but afterwards opening VS2022 normally (without making any changes), the issue was gone. _**Everything was working again.**_ Definitely worth a try opening in safe mode.

Answer (score 885, accepted):

This means that the application is unable to load the EDMX. There are several things which can cause this.

- You might have changed the MetadataArtifactProcessing property of the model to Copy to Output Directory.
- The connection string could be wrong. I know you say you haven't changed it, but if you have changed other things (say, the name of an assembly), it could still be wrong.
- You might be using a post-compile task to embed the EDMX in the assembly, which is no longer working for some reason.

In short, there is not really enough detail in your question to give an accurate answer, but hopefully these ideas should get you on the right track.

**Update:** I've written [a blog post with more complete steps for troubleshooting](http://www.craigstuntz.com/posts/2010-08-13-troubleshooting-entity-framework-connection-strings.html).

Comment: The connectionstring, despite my efforts to compare it with a content-compare utility last time, *was* wrong.

Comment: It was the connectionstring for me too.  When you have Integration Tests that also need connectionsting in its own App.config, things may go out of sync when you update your edmx.

Comment: yes, I did change the settings of the MetadataArtifactProcessing and the post-compile etc. so how do I fix the problem?

Comment: OK, I fixed it by simply setting "Embed"; compiling, then reseting it to the other one. That solved my problem.

Comment: If it is the connection string, and you are doing "DB first" you can tell easily enough (in most cases) by comparing what you get when you "update from database" in the edmx designer with what you have in your web.config or app.config.

Comment: Awesome guide.  For me, I'd copied another connection string which used res://*/Database.MyModel2..., when I REALLY wanted res://*/MyModel1... (Database is a folder inside my Integration Tests project)

Comment: How to know the Assemblie file ?

Comment: Check for entityframework dlls are referenced and copy&paste the connection string from the library as is.

Comment: after following this steps, i got this error _"The entity type Department is not part of the model for the current context."_

Comment: I moved the EDMX file to a sub-folder, but am unsure how to fix it. I've ran `Run Custom Tool` on the TT file, but it hasn't resolved it.

Comment: In my case it was a db table column of type geography, which is not supported

Comment: Going off of what Shimmy said, I changed MetadataArtifactProcessing from embed (which was correct) to copy (which is wrong), rebuilt the project, cleaned the bin folder manually, changed it back to embed, rebuilt, and it worked.  As a side note, get to the MetadataArtifactProcessing by right clicking in an open area of the edmx designer and selecting "Properties" from the context menu.

Comment: After I have refactored database name and replaced it in code at all places have got mentioned exception. Was able to easily update model from database at database tier related project, however after deployment exception always was thrown as there was used different config file. Have used connection string from from project with model at project for deployment and issue was fixed.

Comment: While creating the ADO data model, I didn't accept the default naming values and modified some. This caused the connection string to have strange values. I repeated the same process, accepting all default values this time. Works perfect. Thanks

Comment: Your blog helped me understand the problem. Specifically its not that the edmx is not found, its that the embedded Metadata resources generated from the edmx are not found. At complile time Visual Studio uses a MsBuild task to compile the metadata as 3 embedded resources in the output assembly (which you can see in ILSpy). If the assembly can be found AND it contains the resources then all is well and good - but what about if you're using NANT as the compiler?... well its fixable... https://akutz.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/nant-and-processing-edmx-files/

Comment: Fixed by updating the EDMX (edmx > right-click > update model from database)

Comment: In our case, it was resolved by performing a "Clean Solution" and a rebuild all.

Answer (score 391):

A minor amendment helped me with this problem.

I had a solution with 3 project references:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Project.csdl|res://*/Model.Project.ssdl|res://*/Model.Project.msl;
```

which I changed to:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/;
```

Comment: It fixed it for me, but what the heck does it mean?

Comment: @Lance: I explain this in detail in [this blog post](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/)

Comment: @jocull: No, it won't work in many cases, and will be slow in others. Read my blog post to understand why.

Comment: Moved my .edmx to Model folder and forgot to update the connection string. Great pointer. Thanks. Would have taken me hours to figure out.

Comment: I've done it, and id solved one problem but gives me another `All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered.` - at last for Npgsql. Only full path solved both.

Comment: @MichałPowaga because this solution makes no sense when you have same named class under different namespace. it just ignores the namespace

Comment: this trick fixed my problem, I didn't remember that I've had this problem before unitl I read this solution, now I'm sure I won't forget it again

Comment: 'No connection string named 'xyz' could be found in the application config file.'

Comment: @CraigStuntz, the link to your blog is broken

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim I can't edit the comment, but [here's a newer link](https://www.craigstuntz.com/posts/2010-08-13-troubleshooting-entity-framework-connection-strings.html).

Comment: Get this error: *Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied.*

Answer (score 117):

You can get this exception when the Edmx is in one project and you are using it from another.

The reason is `Res://*/` is a uri which points to resources in the CURRENT assembly.  If the Edm is defined in a different assembly from the code which is using it, res://*/ is not going to work because the resource cannot be found.

Instead of specifying ‘*’, you need to provide the full name of the assembly instead (including public key token).  Eg:

```
res://YourDataAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdefabcedf/YourEdmxFileName.csdl|res://...
```

A better way to construct connection strings is with EntityConnectionStringBuilder:

```
public static string GetSqlCeConnectionString(string fileName)
{
    var csBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

    csBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5";
    csBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};", fileName);

    csBuilder.Metadata = string.Format("res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.csdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.ssdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.msl", 
        typeof(YourObjectContextType).Assembly.FullName);

    return csBuilder.ToString();
}

public static string GetSqlConnectionString(string serverName, string databaseName)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder providerCs = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

    providerCs.DataSource = serverName;
    providerCs.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
    providerCs.IntegratedSecurity = true;

    var csBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

    csBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    csBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerCs.ToString();

    csBuilder.Metadata = string.Format("res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.csdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.ssdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.msl",
        typeof(YourObjectContextType).Assembly.FullName);

    return csBuilder.ToString();
}
```

If you still encounter the exception, open the assembly in reflector and check the filenames for your .csdl, .ssdl and .msl files.  When the resources have different names to the ones specified in the metadata value, it’s not going to work.

Comment: Please consider that "YourEdmxFileName" must be the qualified name e.g. "YourNamespace.YourEdmxFileName", if you use namespaces in your assembly. However, you must remove the part of the namespace that equals to the name of your assembly.

Comment: [MSDN says the second paragraph is wrong.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) "When you use wildcard (*), the Entity Framework has to look through all the assemblies for resources with the correct name."

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the namespace is not relevant, but the embedded file path is.  So even if you inspect the *.Designer.cs file of the associated edmx file and notice that the auto-generated class namespace is MyCompany...whatever, it's not what you should use. Instead the path is assemblyname, solution folder(s) names/file name. For example: "metadata=res://*/EntityModels.<filename>.csdl|" +
            "res://*/EntityModels.<filename>.ssdl|" +
            "res://*/EntityModels.<filename>.msl;"

Comment: @Daniel, that's mostly correct, but note that the namespace and the embedded file path are sometimes the same. You have to look with Reflector (or free alternative to that) to be sure.

Comment: it looks like it works using only the assembly name, without version, publickeytoken, etc. Like: `res://MyAssembly/folder.<filename>.csdl...`

Comment: Confirming that @Craig Stuntz is correct. The wildcard works even when the EDMX is referenced in another assembly.

Answer (score 72):

I had a similar error.  I had recreated the project (long story), and pulled everything over from the old project.  I hadn't realized that my model had been in a directory called 'Model' before, and was now in a directory called 'Models'.  Once I changed the connection in my Web.Config from this:

```
<add name="RecipeManagerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Recipe.csdl
```

to this:

```
<add name="RecipeManagerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Recipe.csdl
```

Everything worked (changed `Model` to `Models`).  Note that I had to change this three places in this string.

Comment: I moved my Entity Framework model from Model to DAL. But then when I wrote a test (a week later) in the test project to test the Linq predicatebuilder. I got this error. I corrected the test projects App.config with how it looked in the main project's web.config - as you said in three places. So your simple answere got me on track.

Comment: Is there a difference between the two?!

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers Model vs ModelS

Comment: Figured out I'd done the same from after reading Craig's blog, but +1 for learning it's important to remember that changes made in your "entities" class library are not automagically made in the config files of projects that reference it. /sigh Glad I'm not alone.

Answer (score 30):

And a quick way to check the model name without Reflector.... look for the directory

> ...obj/{config output}/edmxResourcesToEmbed

and check that the .csdl, .msl, and .ssdl resource files are there. If they are in a sub-directory, the name of the sub-directory must be prepended to the model name.

For example, my three resource files are in a sub-directory **Data**, so my connection string had to be

> metadata=res://*/**Data**.MyModel.csdl|res://*/**Data**.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/**Data**.MyModel.msl;

(versus metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;).

Comment: This was EXACTLY my problem. Lost several hours on this. Thank you so much for this easy explanation

Comment: Great answer, actually explains how to find what your string is.  And shows that subfolders have '.' as delimiters and not '\' or '/'.

Answer (score 18):

This happens to me when I do not clean solution before build new .edmx designer. So just don’t forget to clean solution before you build new .edmx designer. This helps me to skip lot more issues with this one. Bellow the navigation details provided incase you are new in visual studio.

> Click->Build->Clean Solution
>
> Then Click->Build->Rebuild Solution

Hope this helps. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 17):

I also had this problem and it was because the connectionstring in my web.config was slightly different than the one in the app.config of the assembly where my EDMX is located. No idea why it changed, but here are the two different versions.

App.config:

```
<add name="SCMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.SMCSModel.csdl|res://*/Model.SMCSModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.SMCSModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SANDIEGO\sql2008;initial catalog=SCMS;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Web.config:

```
<add name="SCMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.SCMSModel.csdl|res://*/Model.SCMSModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.SCMSModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SANDIEGO\sql2008;initial catalog=SCMS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

What fixed it was simply copying the app.config string (notice the small difference at the end - instead of "`App=EntityFramework`" it wanted "`application name=EntityFramework`") into the web.config and problem was solved. :)

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed my problem. I had 1 project that access DB with EF and another project WCF.
After changing the name of the first project, the connectionString has been changed in the App.config of my first project. So i had to change the connectionString in the project WCF aswell in the web.config :)

Comment: From MSDN documentation about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings: `The .NET Framework data provider for SQL Server (SqlClient) supports many keywords from older APIs, but is generally more flexible and accepts synonyms for many of the common connection string keywords.` Entity Framework connection strings do not share that flexibility, so you must use only the keywords it expects.

Answer (score 16):

This happened to me when I accidentally switched the Build Action of the edmx file (appears under Properties in the IDE) from 'EntityDeploy' to 'None'. EntityDeploy is what populates the metadata for you: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982037.aspx

Comment: This was my fix - I renamed my edmx to .old as I copied it and was trying a few things out, afterwards when I renamed it back the Build Action set it self to none and thus got this error, setting it back to EntityDeploy resolved my issue :)

Comment: I had moved my EDMX file to another folder and had to change the build action to get the embedded resource names to be updated as well.  Thanks!

Comment: This was the solution for me; I'd lost that setting in the process of upgrading to .NET Standard. Thank you for saving my sanity!

Comment: This was my fix too.
Had to set the same property settings of the edmx file than the older project : EntityDeploy / Do not copy / EntityModelCodeGenerator

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes i see this error in my project. I solve that by

1 - Right click on EDMX file

2 - Select `Run Custom Tool` option

3 - Rebuild project

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to rebuild afterwards

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the edmx from a different project, then in the connection string, change...

```
metadata=res://*/Data.DataModel.csdl
```

...to...

```
metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl
```

Comment: This is true, If you want to move it to your new project sub folder, you need to add the `folder.subfolder` before it.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me. I had moved my .edmx file from a dir in one project, to the root of another project, and needed to remove the dir name from all connection strings across my solution.

Answer (score 8):

I've just spent a happy 30 minutes with this. I'd renamed the entities object, renamed the entry in the config file, but there's more  ... you have to change the reference to the csdl as well

very easy to miss - if you're renaming, make sure you get **everything** ....

Answer (score 8):

I spent a whole day on this error.

If you are working with n-tier architecture, or you tried to `separate Models` generated by `EDMX` form DataAccessLayer to `DomainModelLayer`, then you will get this error.

1. The first troubleshooting step is to make sure the Connection strings in `webconfig (UILayer)` and `appconfig (DataAccessLayer)` are the same
2. The second, which is very important, is the **`connection string`** .

   ```
   connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provid.....
   ```

The first part of the connection string is the problem. To see the place where the file names for the .csdl, .ssl, and .msl files come from, look in the solution folder as shown in the picture:

[image]

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I looked into my complied dll with reflector and have seen that the name of the resource was not right. I renamed and it looks fine now.

Answer (score 6):

For my case, it is solved by changing the properties of edmx file.

1. Open the edmx file
2. Right click on any place of the EDMX designer
3. choose properties
4. update Property called "Metadata Artifact Processing" to "Embed in Output Assembly"

this solved the problem for me.
The problem is, when the container try to find the meta data, it cant find it. so simply make it in the same assembly.
this solution will not work if you have your edmx files in another assembly

Comment: +1,000,000 this was the underlying issue for me today. Pains of reorganizing a products namespaces and consolidating assemblies.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this in Visual Studio 2010, VB.net (ASP.NET) 4.0.

During the entity model wizard, you will be able to see the entity connection string. From there you can copy and paste into your connection string.

The only thing I was missing was the "App_Code." in the connections string.

```
entityBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/App_Code.Model.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.msl"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the connecting string in wizard is not correct for app.config. @leqid suggested good way to fix path to the model.

Answer (score 5):

After hours of googling and trying to solve none of the solutions suggested worked. I have listed several solution here. I have also noted the one that worked for me. (I was using EF version 6.1.1, and SQL server 2014 - but an older DB)

1. Rebuilding the project and try again.
2. Close and open VS - I don't know how this works
3. make sure if you have placed the .EDMX file inside a Directory, make sure you include the Directories in your ConnectionString. for example mine is inside DAL folder. SO it looks like this: `connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.nameModel.csdl|res://*/DAL.nameModel.ssdl|res://*/DAL.nameModel.msl;`(these are files. to see them you can toggle Show All Files in solution explorer, under ~/obj/.. directory)

...and many more which I had tried [like: reverting the EntityFramework version to a later version(not sure about it)]

---

**what worked for me:**

from this [article here](http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/12/a-breaking-change-in-entity-framework.html), it helped me solve my problem. I just changed my `ProviderManifestToken="2012"` to `ProviderManifestToken="2008"` in the EDMX file. To do this:

Solution Explorer

1. Right click over file .edmx
2. Open with..
3. Editor XML
4. Change ProviderManifestToken="XXXX" with 2008

I hope that helps.

Comment: I recently had this problem after making seemingly no changes.  Tried restarting VS to no avail, but then it was fixed by cleaning and rebuilding.  So, to others, if you made no changes and none of the rest of this seems relevant, then give a clean/rebuild a try.

Answer (score 4):

<s>The ultimate solution (even after recreating the database on two other machines, as well as the EDMX and other sundries) was to not use the first edition of Entity Framework. Looking forward to evaluating it again in .NET 4.0.</s>

After running into the same problem *again* and searching all over for an answer, I finally found someone who'd had the same problem. It appears that the connection string wasn't correctly generated by Visual Studio's wizard, and the link to the metadata resources was missing an important path.

[v1.0 BUG?: Unable to load the specified metadata resource. Scripts != Models](http://forums.asp.net/p/1409590/3082930.aspx)

**Update 2013-01-16**: Having transitioned to almost exclusively using EF Code First practices (even with existing databases) this problem is no longer an issue. For me, that was a viable solution to reducing the clutter from auto-generated code and configuration and increasing my own control over the product.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this issue was related to renaming my model's edmx file... correcting the app.config connection string for the csdl/ssdl/msl files fixed my issue.

If you're using the EF 4.0 designer to generate your csdl/ssdl/msl, these 3 "files" will actually be stored within the model's main edmx file. In this case, the post by Waqas is pretty much on the mark. It's important to understand that "Model_Name" in his example will need to be changed to whatever the current name of your model's .edmx file (without the .edmx).

Also, if your edmx file is not at the root level of your project, you need to preface Model_Name with the relative path, e.g.

```
res://*/MyModel.WidgetModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.WidgetModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.WidgetModel.msl
```

would specify the csdl/ssdl/msl xml is stored in the model file 'WidgetModel.edmx' which is stored in a folder named 'MyModel'.

Answer (score 4):

My issue and solution, the symptoms were the same "Unable to load the specified metadata resource" but the root cause was different.  I had 2 projects in solution one was the EntityModel and the other the solution.  I actually deleted and recreated the EDMX file in the EntityModel.

The solution was that I had to go back to the Web Application project and add this line into the config file. The new model had changed a few items which had to be duplicated in the "other" project's Web.Config file.  The old configuration was no longer good.

```
     <add name="MyEntities"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
                    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                    provider connection string=&quot;
                    data source=Q\DEV15;initial catalog=whatever;
                    user id=myuserid;password=mypassword;
                    multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                    application name=EntityFramework&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I have written this helper class to create instances of ObjectContext objects when they are defined in a different project than the project using it. I parse the connection string in the config file and replace '*' by the full assembly name.

It is not perfect because it uses reflection to build the object, but it is the most generic way of doing it that I could find.

Hope it helps someone.

```
public static class EntityHelper<T> where T : ObjectContext
{
    public static T CreateInstance()
    {
        // get the connection string from config file
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[typeof(T).Name].ConnectionString;

        // parse the connection string
        var csBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

        // replace * by the full name of the containing assembly
        csBuilder.Metadata = csBuilder.Metadata.Replace(
            "res://*/",
            string.Format("res://{0}/", typeof(T).Assembly.FullName));

        // return the object
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), csBuilder.ToString()) as T;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For all of you `SelftrackingEntities` Users , 
if you have followed the Microsoft Walk-through and separated the Object context class into 
the wcf service project (by linking to the context .tt) so this answer is for you :

part of the shown answers in this post that includes code like :

```
... = string.Format("res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.csdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.ssdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.msl", 
        typeof(YourObjectContextType).Assembly.FullName);
```

WILL NOT WORK FOR YOU  !! the reason is that `YourObjectContextType.Assembly` now resides in a different Assembley (inside the wcf project assembly) ,

So you should replace `YourObjectContextType.Assembly.FullName`  with -->

```
ClassTypeThatResidesInEdmProject.Assembly.FullName
```

have fun.

Answer (score 3):

With having same problem I re-created edmx from Database.
Solves my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that addresses and treats the symptom, not the cause.

Answer (score 3):

Exception is because compiler pointing to non existing Metadata so just Copy `app.config`  connectionstring to `Web.config` ConnectionString

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems with this same error message.  My issue was resolved by closing and re-opening Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue because I renamed an assembly.

I had to also rename it in AssemblyTitle and AssemblyProduct attributes in project Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, and also deleting and re adding the reference to the edmx file.

Then it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just type path as follows instead of {Path.To.The.}: res://*/{Path.To.The.}YourEdmxFileName.csdl|res://*/{Path.To.The.}YourEdmxFileName.ssdl|res://*/{Path.To.The.}YourEdmxFileName.msl

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and solution as per Rick, except that I was importing an existing .edmx to a new project, and while the base namespace didn't matter it was imported into a different subdirectory so I also had to update the connection string inside Web.Config  in three places, to include the different subdirectory naming:

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a solution which contained projects in a Solution Folder, when they were moved to the Solution Root (in order to overcome a suspected bug with the Mvc3AppConverter due to project locations).

Although the solution compiled after all* project references were re-added as needed, the error was thrown when the website was fired up.

The EDMX is in one of the projects which was moved (the 'Data' project), but of course the lack of a reference to the Data project didn't cause a compile error, just a run-time error.

Simply adding the missing reference to the primary project resolved this problem, no need to edit the connection at all.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I had separated Data Access Layer and User Interface layer.
So I have entity connection string for each layer.

Before I modify these two separated connection strings to be the same, I still found that below error.

```
Unable to load the specified metadata resource
```

So I make to be the same connection strings for those two layers (DAL , UI), It work perfect.

**My solution is to make all connection string to be the same no matter where they already presented**.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday and was looking at my code in debug and the output from SQL Profiler.

What I couldn't understand, before I read and understood this post, was why EntityFramework was throwing this error as it was calling the DB. I was looking through hundreds of lines in SQL Profiler trying to work out what was wrong with the database model. I couldn't find anything like the call I was expecting, and to be honest I wasn't certain what I was looking for.

If you are in this position, check the connection string. My guess is that before EntityFramework creates its SQL it will check the model, specified in the metadata part of the connection string. In my case it was wrong. EntityFramework wasn't even making it as far as the DB.

Make sure the names are correct. Once I got that sorted out, I was then seeing calls in SQL Profiler where the ApplicationName was 'EntityFramework' with SQL calling the expected tables.

Answer (score 1):

A poor app.config or web.config file can do this.. I had copied the app.config connection string to my web.config in my UI and ended up entering:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <connectionStrings>
          <add name="name" connectionString="normalDetails"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply hadn't referenced my class library that contained the EDMX file.

Comment: This really helped my particular circumstances, thanks @PeterX.

Answer (score 1):

Using the info from [this blogpost](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/):

Like others have said, res:\\ is a pointer to your resources. To check and make sure your resource names are correct you can use a decompiler like [DotPeek by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to open up your .dll file and see your Resources files.

Or you could open up the watch window while you're debugging and paste in this code to get an array of the resource names in the currently executing assembly.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

That being said, the format of your metadata paths should be something like:

*{my-assembly-name}/{possibly-a-namespace}.{class-name}.{csdl or ssdl or msl}*

Answer (score 1):

In my case none of the answers listed worked and so I'm posting this.

For my case, building on Visual studio and running it with IIS express worked fine. But when I was deploying using Nant scripts as a stand-alone website was giving errors. I tried all the suggestions above and then realized the DLL that was generated by the nant script was much smaller than the one generated by VS. And then I realized that Nant was unable to find the .csdl, .msl and .ssdl files. So then there are really two ways to solve this issue, one is to copy the needed files after visual studio generates them and include these files in the build deployment. And then in Web.config, specify path as:

```
"metadata=~/bin/MyDbContext.csdl|~/bin/MyDbContext.ssdl|~/bin/MyDbContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;...."
```

This is assuming you have manually copied the files into bin directory of the website which you are running. If it's in a different directory, then modify path accordingly.
Second method is to execute EdmGen.exe in Nant script and generate the files and then include them as resources like done in the example below:
https://github.com/qwer/budget/blob/master/nant.build

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that if you have more than one edmx file with same name (Model1 for example), it will give that exception.
I've got same problem when I decided to name all my edmx files (sitting in different projects) as Model1 because I thought they should be independent.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this exception is when you include a related table in an ObjectQuery, but type in the wrong navigation property name.

Example:

```
var query = (from x in myDbObjectContext.Table1.Include("FKTableSpelledWrong") select x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the assembly that contains the model is not loaded:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestOpenWithConfigurationAfterExplicit()
    {
        String dummy = typeof(MallApp).Assembly.FullName;  
        //force the assembly loaded.
        using (DbContext ctx = new DbContext("name=MyContainer))
        {
        }
    }
```

The type `MallApp` lives in the same assembly as the entity model. Without the explicit loading, an `System.Data.MetadataException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

When I got the metadata issue sorted out, I had a follow-on problem in the form of an invokation exception unable to find a connection string for XXXEntities in app.config (where my goal was no dependency on app.config). Through sheer luck I found that referencing System.Data in my unit test project cleared this final hurdle. So to summarise:

1. Use nuget to install Entity Framework to your unit test project.
2. Ensure System.Data.Entity and System.Data are referenced.
3. Sort your connection string as described very well here.
4. Pass the connection string to your partial class constructor.

I now have my metadata in a class library which can update from a reference db, and I can point my application and unit tests to any db on any server at runtime.

Addendum: When I moved my edmx to a folder, I got the error again. After a bit of research, I found that you want your metadata string to look like: metadata=res://EPM.DAL/Models.EPM.csdl, where EPM.DAL is the name of the assembly and EPM.edmx is in the models folder.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem for me. My class name was different to my file name. The connectionstring generated had the class name and not the file name in. Solution for me was just to rename my file to match the class name.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my emdx file was deleted by a prebuild command, quite simply. Took me a while before realizing it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was because I was building the connection string using a EntityConnectionStringBuilder. Make sure your  Metadata property is using the Model name (including the namespace)

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after moving a large solution from one folder in Source Control Explorer to another.  We don't check the package folder into Team Foundation and so I think VS downloaded packages automatically.  This upgraded my EF form v6.1.2 to v6.1.3.

The problem went away when I downgraded to the original v6.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on 27 Sep 2019.

My API is in Dot net core Targeting to .net framework.
edmx is in a different class library which is in .net framework only.

I observed that when I try to call that edmx from API .. for some reason I got that error.

What I did is, go to the obj folder of API and delete everything.
then clean the API project and try again and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was reflecting an old program, I faced the same problem. I went through previous answers, and I succeeded to solve it by putting the 3 files of "Model.csdl", "Model.ssdl" and "Model.msl" in the bin directory, and also beside the entities class.
After that change the metdata part of the entities connection string in web.config to be:

```
metadata=~/bin/Model.csdl|~/bin/Model.ssdl|~/bin/Model.msl
```

and the program ran successfully withput displaying this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Also in my case syntax error in the XML structure of the EDMX was the reason. I recognized that after VS was not able to show the graph diagram and opened the XML editor instead.

An earlier merge was the root cause of the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error upon upgrading my project to .NET 6, and none of the previous solutions solved my issue.

You may want to check if your .edmx file has the following two properties set as follows:

- Build Action: EntityDeploy
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always

Ultimately my issue was that the files referenced in my .edmx file were not being generated.

Answer (score -1):

i deleted the \bin and \obj folders from all of the projects in the solution, then rebuilt the soluition and it worked fine

Comment: Did you go through *all* 44 (!) answers before adding your answer?