# Error reached after genereated entity framework classes by edmgen tool

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmgen

First I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource), but this knowledge did not help to solve my problems.

In initial I've created edmx file by Visual Studio. Generated files with names:

- uqsModel.Designer.cs
- uqsModel.edmx

This files are located on App_Code folder.

And my web app work normally. 
In Web Config generated connectionstring automatically.

```
<add name="uqsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.uqsModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.uqsModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.uqsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=aemloviji\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=uqs;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Then I had to generate classes by the instrument **edmgen tool**(full generation mode).
Generated new files with names:

- uqsModel.cs
- uqsModel.csdl
- uqsModel.msl
- uqsModel.ssdl
- uqsViews.cs

it save new classed to the folder where edmx files located before, and remove existing edmx files. And when page redirrects to any web page server side code fails. 
And problem: **Unable to load the specified metadata resource**.

Some idea, please.

Comment: Are you running in medium trust on IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be associated with the fact that you have generated metadata in the form of .csdl, .ssdl, and .msl files, and your connection string points to the resource that should be embedded to the project dll (which is likely to be unavailable in your Web Site). 
The solution is to correct the path to metadata like the following:

```
metadata=~\App_Code\uqsModel.csdl|~\App_Code\uqsModel.ssdl|~\App_Code\uqsModel.msl
```

More information is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716677.aspx).