# Error when using entity framework library in Quartz.NET project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, quartz.net

I am writing a Quartz.NET scheduler application which obtains some data from an entity framework library.

When Quartz.NET fires the job, my log files show the following error, despite app.config files being present in the output directory for each of my DLLs.

> The specified named connection is either not found in the
>   configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
>   or not valid.

Does anybody have any idea as to why this might be?

The entity framework application works well when utilised by a web application.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/q/3491165/377996

Comment: Connection string must be in app.config of your executable or in the main web.config of your web / service application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the connection string to the bottom of Quartz.Server.exe.config.