# entity framework Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: .net, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

I hope someone can help with this. i have tried following other posts on here and dozens on other sites but i can get this working.

the entity framework was all working, then the next day just started giving me the error: Unable to load the specified metadata resource. on the constructor of the entities class.

I have checked the connection strings, deleted and re added everything but i still cant get this working.

my model namespace is WraithNath.co.uk.Models

the metadata artificat is embed in assembly

my connection strings are as follows:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL2008;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\WraithNath.co.uk.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.WraithNath.co.uk.csdl|res://*/Models.WraithNath.co.uk.ssdl|res://*/Models.WraithNath.co.uk.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQL2008;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\WraithNath.co.uk.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I cant find the 3 files i need in the assembly when looking at it in Reflector.

Is there a step by step guide to sort this out? i have already tried every link on the first 3 pages of google for search results 'entity framework Unable to load the specified metadata resource'.

Comment: When you open your EDMX model's properties what is your value in Metadata Artifact Processing property?

Comment: My problem was i had no Models. in front of my entity model.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

[Craig Stuntz](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/) has written an extensive (in my opinion) blog post on troubleshooting this exact error message, I personally would start there.

The following `res:` (resource) references need to point to your model.

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=
    res://*/Models.WraithNath.co.uk.csdl|
    res://*/Models.WraithNath.co.uk.ssdl|
    res://*/Models.WraithNath.co.uk.msl;
```

Make sure each one has the name of your .edmx file after the "*/", with the "edmx" changed to the extension for that res (.csdl, .ssdl, or .msl).

It also may help to specify the assembly rather than using "//*/".

Worst case, you can check everything (a bit slower but should always find the resource) by using

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=
        res://*/;provider= <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: thanks, i cant believe i didnt find that site!

Comment: @PsychoCoder - I did look at this, but when you mentioned again I actually read it properly and it solved my problem

Comment: In my case I had just re-created the model using a different name, but with the same connection string. This was the exact solution I needed.

Comment: I dont understand this answer :(

Comment: That site was the answer! In my case, I was looking at the wrong config file. Thanks for mentioning that site!