# MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have one solution with 2 project and I am updating database with EF 6.0 .I am able to update the db if I simply update db from one pr0ject by adding reference of project which has code of EF.
But  if I add Service reference and calling that service to update db then I get error 
MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource"

Please help me out.

Comment: Refer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739959/entity-framework-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding EF in web config file of my service project.

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding EF in web config file of my service project.