# Unable to load the specified metadata resource. On code first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

Hi i am trying to create the tables using code first approach on EF5. I have created a database called "DEV_Database" on a server called "SERVER01".

After I enter "enable-migrations -contexttypename Entities -force" on package manager console I get  this error "Unable to load the specified metadata resource."

I had this connection String auto generated for me by VS12, which words fine with other approaches.
Can anyone help me with this. My connection string is below.

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER01;initial catalog=DEV_Database;persist security info=True;user id=USER1;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Comment: Possible dublicate [entity framework Unable to load the specified metadata resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739959/entity-framework-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

Comment: How can it be duplicate and i already checked that link and its not related to my issue. My issue is with the .csdl .ssdl and .msl files.