# ASP MVC, EF Code first Unable to load the specified metadata resource (without edmx)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I get the following error when I run my site:

> Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Here is my connection string:

```
 <add name="Context" connectionString="metadata=res://*/database.csdl|res://*/database.ssdl|res://*/database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=127.0.0.1,2014;Database=myDbName;User Id=sa;Password=myPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

After I looking for a solution I found some answers that doesn't help me to solve this problem, because they say I should apply some changes on `.edmx` file but I don't have any `.edmx` file in my project.

My project is code-first and as far as I know code-first project's doesn't have any `.edmx` file.

I also check related firewall port on server and it's okay.

Here are some solutions that I can't use these to solve this problem:

[entity framework Unable to load the specified metadata resource [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739959/entity-framework-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

[MetadataException Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

[Unable to load the specified metadata resource. Scripts != Models](https://forums.asp.net/p/1409590/3082930.aspx)

[System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351898/system-data-metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

I use VS17, EF 6.2 and here is my solution structure:

```
-- myPrj.web
-- myPrj.Model
-- myPrj.Repository
-- myPrj.Service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string is for a database first context. For code first, you should use a simpler version, which contains only the information to connect to the database (metadata are created dynamically). For your case, try with this:

```
<add name="Context" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1,2014;Database=myDbName;User Id=sa;Password=myPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```