# System.Data.MetadataException - seems more stubborn than most people's

Tags: entity-framework

I have gone through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource) and the links, and still can't solve my issue.

I have changed my config to name the assembly, but it makes no odds.

We recently moved the projects and think that might be an issue - but how to solve it if so. I don't quite understand how EF when running finds the cdsl etc. files I thought they were embedded in the dll [it is set to do so]?

The service having the issue doesn't directly use EF itself, it uses another DLL which DOES. I also added a direct ref to the DLL but no joy.

Also, the same code (the dll that contains the functionality, not the wrapper service) using the same connections strings works fine in my system test project via the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be down to incorrect initialisation of StructureMap and not really to do with EF itself.