# Connection string "Unable to load the specified metadata resource" Issue

Tags: entity-framework, appharbor

I am trying to connect my Entity Framework mappings to be integrated with an Sql server on a hosted site.

This issue can be found in the following stack trace:

```
[MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.]
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +387
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource..ctor(String originalPath, String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +72
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +222
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +74
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry) +68
```

I am assume that my connection string is not being setup correctly, as I need to generate this string dynamically at runtime. The String looks as follows:

```
<add name="Model1Container-providerConnectionString" 
     connectionString="data source=something.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;
     User ID=**; 
     Password=**;
     Initial Catalog=dbd5d3955e11834e1088929f9d005af0a8;
     user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework" />
```

Then on run time the string is constructed as follows:

```
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string baseConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Model1Container-providerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = baseConnectionString;
        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl";

        return entityBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Been working on this issue for a few days now, would very much appreciate the communities expertise in finding a working solution.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

Comment: see the Question of stackoverflow.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource