# Entity Framework: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I decided to move `Entity Connection String` from `app.config` to code. However after setting it up like this:

```
    public static string GetConnectionString() {
        string connection = "";

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = dbServer;
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = dbInitialCatalog;

        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        sqlBuilder.UserID = dbUserName;
        sqlBuilder.Password = dbPasswWord;
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entity = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
       // entity.Name = "EntityBazaCRM";
        entity.Metadata = @"res://*/Data.System.csdl|res://*/Data.System.ssdl|res://*/Data.System.msl";

        entity.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        entity.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        connection = entity.ToString();

        return connection;
    }
```

I have an exception thrown `Unable to load the specified metadata resource.` in .Designer.cs.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new EntityBazaCRM object.
    /// </summary>
    public EntityBazaCRM(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "EntityBazaCRM")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

If I define .Name inside my Entity creator it throws another exception

`"Other keywords are not allowed when the 'Name' keyword is specified." (System.ArgumentException)  Exception Message = "Other keywords are not allowed when the 'Name' keyword is specified.", Exception Type = "System.ArgumentException"`

I know I'm missing something that I have to change so that self generated code uses new connection string but where to look for it?

Comment: see here.  this is a way good answer :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After reading [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource) article and [this blog](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/) I changed:

```
  entity.Metadata = @"res://*/Data.System.csdl|res://*/Data.System.ssdl|res://*/Data.System.msl";
```

To:

```
  entity.Metadata = "res://*/";
```

And it works :-)

Comment: Looks like good solution, but is there any harm in doing this?

Comment: Not that I know. I'm using it since that time till today ;)

Comment: As long as you only have one model, it shouldn't be an issue. This solved it for me! +1

Comment: throws ArgumentException:
Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to the new csproj format(Visual studio 2017 with simple format) after that I started getting this error.  The csproj has a feature where you don't need to include each file instead it includes all the relevant files under the folder by default so the entity framework files are treated same way so those are not embedded into the assembly by default.

I need to go and manually change the build action of my edml file(edmx in case of Microsoft entity framework) to 'DevartEntityDeploy' (I hope it is EntityDeploy for Microsoft Entity framework)and build it which solved my problem

[image]