# System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, edmx, devart

My connection strings are as follows:

```
<add name="RollCallDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://System.Engine/RollcallNS.csdl|res://System.Engine/RollcallNS.ssdl|res://System.Engine/RollcallNS.msl;provider=Devart.Data.Oracle;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=user;Password=password;Server=127.0.0.1;Direct=True;Sid=ORCL&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

my code are as follows:

```
using (var db= new RollCallDBEntities()) //ok
{
   var query = db.TBL_ROLLCALL.ToList(); //Unable to load the specified metadata resource.
}
```

my assembly:

```
System.Engine
```

Anyone have any ideas?

these links did not soled my problem:
[MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)
[entity framework Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739959/entity-framework-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)
[Entity Framework: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971698/entity-framework-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)
[Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648212/unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

Comment: Are you sure that the resources were embedded in the assembly? Use ildasm or reflector to double check they are there.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to replace 'System.Engine' with '*' in all three places.

Comment: @Pawel TBL_ROLLCALL are as follows `namespace System.Engine
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    [Serializable, EdmEntityType(NamespaceName="RollCallNS", Name="TBL_ROLLCALL"), DataContract(IsReference=true)]
    public class TBL_ROLLCALL : EntityObject
    {...`

Comment: this does not answer my question I was asking about resources embedded in the assembly and not about the class itself since the exception indicates the problem is with the resources.

Comment: @xanatos i undelete the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer to http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=22092 .

If this doesn't help, please specify:

- are you working with ADO.NET Entity Data Model (.edmx) or [Devart Entity Model](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/ed-vs-edm.html) (.edml)?
- the value of your model file's Build Action    property
- the value of the Metadata Artifact Processing property of    your model
- the build number (x.xx.xxx) of your dotConnect for Oracle
- the version of your Visual Studio
- follow *Pawel*'s advice to check if resources were    embedded in
  the assembly

Answer (score 83):

I was getting an exception like this. The problem was that I renamed my `.edmx` file and forgot to change the name in EF `Web.config` file's connection string:

```
metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;
```

Comment: exactly. if you have a different project to access your data remember that you should have also 2 different connection strings... thanks for the tip

Comment: thank you ... Someone copy paste connection string for another context pointed to the same DB. So the EDMX was wrong!

Comment: In my case, I move the .edmx file to another location and forget to change the connection string to point to the new location of .edmx files

Comment: Do not forget to specify DB entity's namespace in the metadata section

Comment: @user3873265 how do I do that? can you provide a sample?

Comment: @NitinSawant connectionString="metadata=res://*/+++.ModelName.csdl|res://*/+++.ModelName.ssdl|...", where +++ - is a namespace's name of entity model. Often folks forget to add/change it.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest solution that resolved this for me was to **remove the obj folder** which sit at the same level as the bin folder and **re-run the application**, my god it took way longer than it needed

Comment: Which `obj` folder? The one is inside `presentation` and the other is inside `DAL`

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil the one for the project throwing the error

Comment: Thanks, I got it fixed by copying the connection string from App.config to Web.config.

Comment: I got it fixed by copying the connection string from App.config to Web.config same as Zeeshean above

Comment: Was getting the same problem in my web application, this helped, thanks

Comment: Running an old old .net 4.5 framework proj and this saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 3):

right click on the project>>`Clean`>> and then `Rebuild`

worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I used EntityFramework 6.0 in one solution which included multiple projects such as WebSite level project, DataAccess level project. In my solution, the migrations should be happened in DataAccess level project.

When I run Add-Migration command in Package Manager Console, raised "Unable to load the specified metadata resource".

Finally, I found I set the WebSite level project as "Startup" project and this trigger above exception. It seems system will auto checking the connection string settings in the StartUp project first. And my data connection string set in WebSite level project is

"metadata=res://*/ApplicationEntities.csdl|res://*/ApplicationEntities.ssdl|res://*/ApplicationEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.;initial catalog=YourDatabaseName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework""

which is not correct for code first.

The correct connection string should be:

"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"

Conclusion, always check the "connectionStrings" section in web.config in the "StartUp" project of solution first.

Comment: Thank you. Copying the connection string from the EF project to the entry point project's config file solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem and it was because I was going from Entity Framework Model First to Entity Framework Code First, and had forgotten to change the EDMX connectionstring to a 'regular' connection string.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is specific for Devart Entity developer edml file.

When I upgraded the csproj format(Visual studio 2017 with simple format) I got this error. The csproj has a feature where you don't need to include each file instead it includes all the relevant files under the folder by default so the entity framework files are treated same way as cs files so those are not embedded into the assembly by default.

I need to manually change the build action of my edml file to 'DevartEntityDeploy' which resolved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the error with Devart DotConnect for Oracle 8.5. I just

1. renamed the extension edml -> edmx and;
2. changed the associated DevartEntityDeploy property of the file to EntityDeploy and the error disapeared.

Not that you can easily spot this error without browsing your website by analyzing the content of your data access Dll with JustDecompile/DotPeek/DnSpy looking for the ressource folder filled with *dl files:

[image: DotPeek dll listing]

If the Resources folder is empty or missing, you will have this error.

Answer (score 1):

We upgraded from **.net core 1** to **3.1** and from **visual studio 2015** to **visual studio 2019**. We noticed that the **Build Action** for some files has been reset. So we changed back the **Build Action** from **None** to **Content** for all files ending with .tt, and their **Copy to Output directory** to **Do Not Copy**.
We also had to change the build action of the **.edmx** file to **EntityDeploy** and its **copy to output directory** value to **Do Not Copy**.
HTH someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure of what the correct path is for your Metadata files, you can find out by compiling your application, then opening the DLL using JetBrains' dotPeek and looking in the Resources folder to find the .csdl etc. file.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem and it was because I forgot to reference the project that contained the EDMX file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar product with devart mysqlconnect - maybe this might help.

I have a project called EFModels which contains the .edml file and is referenced by other projects.

I noticed that the Release version of a project that referenced EFModels contains the EFModels.dll but it was much smaller in size (127kb vs 437kb) than the Debug version of EfModels.dll. Moving the EFModels.dll from the debug version into the Release version solved the issue for me as for some reason the Release version did not embed the ssdl etc.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem becaue I was the missing `entityFramework` config section in the `app.config`.

I had this:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

But not this:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, in my case, the problem was on changing the Model and the file named "...Web Deploy.pubxml" had the "metadata=res://*/Models.***.csdl", etc. with the incorrect name (not updated). After manual correction it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case excluding the .edmx file and including it worked!