# Entity Framwork Unable to Load the specified metadata resource

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have set up a SQL Server and EF in my project.

```
MPSDBEntities mpsEntities = new MPSDBEntities();
```

And it works fine when I do a save changes. e.g

```
mpsEntities.SaveChanges();
```

it updates the database (does it mean my connection string is correct?)

However, whenever I tried to perform any kind of load data/SQL from the EF, such as

```
var temp = mpsEntities.CARD_BY_CHECKTYPE.Where(x => (x.CHECK_TYPE == "AA2")).ToList();
```

It would throw an exception of

> Unable to Load the specified metadata resource.

Here is my connection string, which I doubt is where the problem is at:

```
<add name="MPSDBEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/MPSDBModel.csdl|res://*/MPSDBModel.ssdl|res://*/MPSDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PAE0DT-DDWB282\MPS2;initial catalog=MPS;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I went through the following posts. They didn't solve my problem.

[System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351898/system-data-metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

[MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

[Entity Framework: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971698/entity-framework-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

[Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648212/unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

Anyone know what the problem is?
Thank you.

@petryuno1

Here is my `DbContext`, if this is what you are asking..

```
public partial class MPSDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public MPSDBEntities() : base("name=MPSDBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<CARD_BY_CHECKTYPE> CARD_BY_CHECKTYPE { get; set; }
    ........
}
```

Comment: What does your DbContext look like?

Comment: @petryuno1 See my edited post.  These were all generated automatically when I do the Add ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

Comment: You have an .edmx file for your entity? If so, can you run an 'Update Model From Database' command on it?

Comment: I clicked Update Model From Database. and then click Finish?  Nothing really changed.....same error message....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

Changing from this:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Project.csdl|res://*/Model.Project.ssdl|res://*/Model.Project.msl;
```

change to:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/;
```

And add the rest of your connection string after. Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried.  Still yelled at me the same error message.  But thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you check both the "App.config" and the "Web.config"?

Comment: Thank you..I don't see a Web.config in my solution explorer.....Sorry i didn't put this as a C# WPF project other than an ASP.NET....

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your connection string, have you tried another select query?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Yes.  I've tried even the simplest ones such as  var temp = mpsEntities.CARD_BY_CHECKTYPE.ToList();  Didn't work neither.   But var temp = mpsEntities.CARD_BY_CHECKTYPE without ToList() didn't give me that Unable to Load the specified metadata resource exception though.