# Is it possible to get the calling objects type programatically?

Tags: c#

[I got this idea from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958579/how-to-use-a-dynamic-connection-string-using-a-model-first-approach-but-still-us) It converts an old style connection string to a modelFirst Connection string:

```
public static class ConnectionStringExtensions
{
    public static string GetEntityConnectionString(this string connectionString, Type contextType)
    {
        var prefix = contextType.Namespace.Replace(contextType.Assembly.GetName().Name, "");

        if (prefix.Length > 0
            && prefix.StartsWith("."))
        {
            prefix = prefix.Substring(1, prefix.Length - 1);
        }

        if (prefix.Length > 1 && !prefix.EndsWith("."))
        {
            prefix += ".";
        }


        var csBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
            ProviderConnectionString = connectionString,
            Metadata = String.Format("res://{0}/{1}.csdl|"
                                     + "res://{0}/{1}.ssdl|"
                                     + "res://{0}/{1}.msl"
                , contextType.Assembly.FullName
                , prefix + contextType.Name)
        };

        return csBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

This works great. My question is when I call it:

```
string connString =   ConfigurationMananager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString;
var dbContext = new MyDbContext(connString.ToEntityConnectionString(typeof(MyDbContext);
```

The call looks redundant with the instantiation and then passing the type into the extension method. Is there a way to get that programatically based on what constructor it was passed into

Comment: Why create an extension method at all?  Why not put that code into a private method of `MyDbContext` and then call that method inside the constructor?  Then your calling code only needs to be `var dbContext = new MyDbContext(connString);`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I have multiple contexts to deal with and I am planning to create a nuget package out of this and use it in other applications.

Comment: since it is an extension method, so, your call can be var dbContext = connString.GetEntityConnectionString(this.GetType()).

Comment: @EricLemes  I was hoping to call the method without passing anything into the method. I like that idea better than passing in an explicit type. But I didn't know if I could infer the type in the extension method based on the call

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't possible. You'll need to send the DbContext type to the method some way, or turn it into an constant inside your class. I don't know how to get the type of the caller from inside a method, and I think it's a bad ideal. That will be a collateral effect inside the method. If the DbContext is needed for the processing, it should be in the method signature. If you'll never change it, it should be a constant.

Comment: @EricLemes Thanks for the input. Put you're comment about using this.GetType() and I'll accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it isn't possible.

You'll need to send the DbContext type to the method some way, or turn it into an constant inside your class.

I don't know how to get the type of the caller from inside a method, and I think it's a bad idea. That will be a collateral effect inside the method. If the DbContext is needed for the processing, it should be in the method signature. If you'll never change it, it should be a constant.

You can try to send the type using "this.GetType()" or var dbContext = connString.GetEntityConnectionString(this.GetType()).