# Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having some serious problems with Entity Framework and I can't seem to figure out whats going on.

I tried many options provided on: [MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource) and the famous Craig Stuntz's blog posting located at: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/

I have 3 projects for the sake of brevity:

Funscribe.Data (EDMX file located here)

Funscribe.Console (Console app)

Funscribe.Web (MVC 3 app)

Originally it was just the MVC app and I recently added this new console project.

I copied the connection string from web.config and applied it to my app.config:

```
<add name="FundirectoryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Fundirectory.csdl|res://*/Fundirectory.ssdl|res://*/Fundirectory.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Funscribe;user id=sys_Funscribe;password=blah;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My mvc app continues to work, but when I run the console app, i get the dreaded:

**"Unable to load the specified metadata resource."**

I tried changing the connection string to the wild card setting:

```
<add name="FundirectoryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Funscribe;user id=sys_Funscribe;password=blah;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I get:
**The specified default EntityContainer name 'FundirectoryEntities' could not be found in the mapping and metadata information.**

I tried changing it to specify the assembly:

```
<add name="FundirectoryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://Funscribe.Data.dll/Fundirectory.csdl|res://Funscribe.Data.dll/Fundirectory.ssdl|res://Funscribe.Data.dll/Fundirectory.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Funscribe;user id=sys_Funscribe;password=blah;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I get:
**Unable to resolve assembly 'Funscribe.Data.dll'.**

I am lost on what I should do here. I just upgraded this project to Visual Studio 2012 (I introduce this new console app after converting to VS 2012).

I also noticed that the Funscribe.Data.dll is located within the console project's bin folder, i manually deleted these files and watch it get recreated. ***And what puzzles me is the web app continues to work properly***!

All projects are on .NET 4.0. The console app uses .NET 4.0 not the client profile verison.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The metadata parameter for an application with an Entity Framework model called `Model.edmx` in an assembly called Simple `Mvc.Data.dll` might look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=
            res://Simple Mvc.Data.dll/Model.csdl|
            res://Simple Mvc.Data.dll/Model.ssdl|
            res://Simple Mvc.Data.dll/Model.msl;provider= <!-- ... -->
```

So you can see there is one reference for each of the three parts of the EDMX that we need at runtime. They all work in the same way, so let’s examine just the first more closely. The CSDL reference looks like this:

```
        res://Simple Mvc.Data.dll/Model.csdl
```

**It specifies three things:**

- We’re loading the CSDL from a resource. That’s the `"res://" part.`
- The name of the assembly which contains the resource, `"Simple Mvc.Data.dll"`. If your assembly is strong named, you can specify a strong name, in all its verbose glory, here.
- The name of the resource itself, `"Model.csdl"`. Do not confuse this with the EDMX or model name. In this case they happen to be the same, except for the extension, but that’s not always true!

> It will probably fail if your resources don’t happen to have the same
>   name as your model, or if the assembly doesn’t happen to be loaded.

For more information check this out [**Troubleshooting Entity Framework Connection Strings**](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Awesome answer.  This helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the connectionString is trying to find the resources files but unable to. What I did to solve my problem is:

Right-Click EDMX diagram -> Go to properties -> Connection -> Metadata Artifact Processing -> Then change to **Copy to Output Directory** and rebuild.

This will change your metadata connectionstring path point to the resources he's trying to find.

Answer (score 2):

Rebuilding solution in Visual Studio helped me.

It is on Build -> Rebuild

Comment: Mine too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

This means that the application is unable to load the EDMX.

There are several things which can cause this, but most likely, due to invalid connection string.

Possible Solutions:

1.Check connection string 
2.Refresh model.edmx
3.Select option "Update Model from database"  in model.edmx

http://mvc4asp.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I delete my EDMX file in project and create it again with a new name, eg. before it was Home_Model, later it is Home_Cost.
when I try to invoke the below code, it has "Unable to load the specified metadata resource." error.
/////

```
    using (var currentEntities = new masterEntities())
    {
        currentUser = currentEntities.Home_User.FirstOrDefault(
            x => x.UserLoginAccount == userLoginAccount && x.UserPwd == userPwd);

    }
```

////
so in Web.config, I modify the 
metadata configuation from Home_Model to Home_Cost.

then it works.
obviously, VS2015(my version) didn't update web.config when I delete/create edmx.