# AddObject is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5

In my **.net (3.5)** application with **EF** I use following code to insert new record, but **AddObject()** is not working.

I am surprise because it happens first time, even before when I had worked on EF at that time its was working.

**My code**

```
    public void NewAirline(string name, string sname, string remark)
    {
        GsecEntities e = new GsecEntities();
        tbAirLine al = new tbAirLine()
        {
            Name = name,
            Remark = remark,
            ShortName = sname
        };
        e.tbAirLines.AddObject(al);
        e.SaveChanges();
    }
```

As suggestion Here I am writing code of tbAirline

```
    public partial class GsecEntities : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new GsecEntities object using the connection string found in the 'GsecEntities' section of the application configuration file.
    /// </summary>
    public GsecEntities() : 
            base("name=GsecEntities", "GsecEntities")
    {
        this.OnContextCreated();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new GsecEntities object.
    /// </summary>
    public GsecEntities(string connectionString) : 
            base(connectionString, "GsecEntities")
    {
        this.OnContextCreated();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new GsecEntities object.
    /// </summary>
    public GsecEntities(global::System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection) : 
            base(connection, "GsecEntities")
    {
        this.OnContextCreated();
    }
    partial void OnContextCreated();
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbAirLines in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbAirLine> tbAirLines
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._tbAirLines == null))
            {
                this._tbAirLines = base.CreateQuery<tbAirLine>("[tbAirLines]");
            }
            return this._tbAirLines;
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbAirLine> _tbAirLines;
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbBanks in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbBank> tbBanks
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._tbBanks == null))
            {
                this._tbBanks = base.CreateQuery<tbBank>("[tbBanks]");
            }
            return this._tbBanks;
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbBank> _tbBanks;
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbCities in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbCity> tbCities
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._tbCities == null))
            {
                this._tbCities = base.CreateQuery<tbCity>("[tbCities]");
            }
            return this._tbCities;
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbCity> _tbCities;
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbCommodities in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbCommodity> tbCommodities
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._tbCommodities == null))
            {
                this._tbCommodities = base.CreateQuery<tbCommodity>("[tbCommodities]");
            }
            return this._tbCommodities;
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbCommodity> _tbCommodities;
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbCountries in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbCountry> tbCountries
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._tbCountries == null))
            {
                this._tbCountries = base.CreateQuery<tbCountry>("[tbCountries]");
            }
            return this._tbCountries;
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbCountry> _tbCountries;
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbFlights in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbFlight> tbFlights
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._tbFlights == null))
            {
                this._tbFlights = base.CreateQuery<tbFlight>("[tbFlights]");
            }
            return this._tbFlights;
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbFlight> _tbFlights;
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbGrpCommodities in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbGrpCommodity> tbGrpCommodities
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._tbGrpCommodities == null))
            {
                this._tbGrpCommodities = base.CreateQuery<tbGrpCommodity>("[tbGrpCommodities]");
            }
            return this._tbGrpCommodities;
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbGrpCommodity> _tbGrpCommodities;
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbPersons in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbPerson> tbPersons
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._tbPersons == null))
            {
                this._tbPersons = base.CreateQuery<tbPerson>("[tbPersons]");
            }
            return this._tbPersons;
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbPerson> _tbPersons;
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbPersonTypes in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbPersonType> tbPersonTypes
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._tbPersonTypes == null))
            {
                this._tbPersonTypes = base.CreateQuery<tbPersonType>("[tbPersonTypes]");
            }
            return this._tbPersonTypes;
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<tbPersonType> _tbPersonTypes;
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbAirLines in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void AddTotbAirLines(tbAirLine tbAirLine)
    {
        base.AddObject("tbAirLines", tbAirLine);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbBanks in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void AddTotbBanks(tbBank tbBank)
    {
        base.AddObject("tbBanks", tbBank);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbCities in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void AddTotbCities(tbCity tbCity)
    {
        base.AddObject("tbCities", tbCity);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbCommodities in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void AddTotbCommodities(tbCommodity tbCommodity)
    {
        base.AddObject("tbCommodities", tbCommodity);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbCountries in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void AddTotbCountries(tbCountry tbCountry)
    {
        base.AddObject("tbCountries", tbCountry);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbFlights in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void AddTotbFlights(tbFlight tbFlight)
    {
        base.AddObject("tbFlights", tbFlight);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbGrpCommodities in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void AddTotbGrpCommodities(tbGrpCommodity tbGrpCommodity)
    {
        base.AddObject("tbGrpCommodities", tbGrpCommodity);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbPersons in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void AddTotbPersons(tbPerson tbPerson)
    {
        base.AddObject("tbPersons", tbPerson);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for tbPersonTypes in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void AddTotbPersonTypes(tbPersonType tbPersonType)
    {
        base.AddObject("tbPersonTypes", tbPersonType);
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// There are no comments for GsecModel.tbAirLine in the schema.
/// </summary>
/// <KeyProperties>
/// Id
/// </KeyProperties>
[global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="GsecModel", Name="tbAirLine")]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
[global::System.Serializable()]
public partial class tbAirLine : global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new tbAirLine object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Initial value of Id.</param>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public static tbAirLine CreatetbAirLine(long id)
    {
        tbAirLine tbAirLine = new tbAirLine();
        tbAirLine.Id = id;
        return tbAirLine;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for property Id in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public long Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnIdChanging(value);
            this.ReportPropertyChanging("Id");
            this._Id = global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            this.ReportPropertyChanged("Id");
            this.OnIdChanged();
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private long _Id;
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    partial void OnIdChanging(long value);
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    partial void OnIdChanged();
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for property Name in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmScalarPropertyAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnNameChanging(value);
            this.ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
            this._Name = global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            this.ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
            this.OnNameChanged();
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private string _Name;
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    partial void OnNameChanging(string value);
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    partial void OnNameChanged();
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for property ShortName in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmScalarPropertyAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public string ShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ShortName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnShortNameChanging(value);
            this.ReportPropertyChanging("ShortName");
            this._ShortName = global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            this.ReportPropertyChanged("ShortName");
            this.OnShortNameChanged();
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private string _ShortName;
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    partial void OnShortNameChanging(string value);
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    partial void OnShortNameChanged();
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for property Remark in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmScalarPropertyAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    public string Remark
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Remark;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnRemarkChanging(value);
            this.ReportPropertyChanging("Remark");
            this._Remark = global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            this.ReportPropertyChanged("Remark");
            this.OnRemarkChanged();
        }
    }
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private string _Remark;
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    partial void OnRemarkChanging(string value);
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    partial void OnRemarkChanged();
}
```

And its give following error

> Error  1   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery' does not contain a definition for 'AddObject' and no extension method 'AddObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: pls post the implementation of tbAirLine.AddObject()

Comment: Seems I am also shocked. As I know nothing is wrong with your this code. As I thinks it should work perfectly...

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: do you have exception?

Comment: Can we see `GsecEntities`, especially `tbAirLines` property/function?

Comment: @swtdrgn check it out.... there are some other tables details are also available, so you can ignore it....

Comment: do you have the "System.Data.Objects" namespace referenced in the class where "NewAirline" function is defined?

Comment: @daryal there was not but now I had put the line `using System.Data.Objects;`. But nothing happen, still that problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET version 3.5 exposes `ObjectQuery<T>` versus `ObjectSet<T>` in .NET 4.0. Therefor you will need to use either `e.AddTotbAirLines(tbAirLine)` or `e.AddObject("tbAirLines", tbAirLine)`. Both can be found on line 185 of the submitted generated code. In .NET 4.0 they decided to implement it like you were showing in your question.

Comment: In that case you might want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource) for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks buddy, your solution works. If you near by me I will by you a bear... and +1 for nice answer...