# Console WCF Service Host with ADO.NET / Entity Framework C# / .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, entity-framework

I have created a C# .NET WCF Service which utilizes ADO.NET / Entity Framework, I host this service inside a Console Application.

```
using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HyperionDataService.HyperionDataService)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service Active");
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
```

When attempting to consume this service in an application, I am sent to a line of code inside my WCF Service:

```
    public List<Extract> DumpExtracts()
    {
        using (var context = new HyperionSmokeEntities())
        {
            return context.Extracts.ToList(); //Error on this line
        }
    }
```

I receive the error: *Unable to load the specified metadata resource.*

My App.Config clearly states my Metadata resource:

```
 <connectionStrings><add name="HyperionSmokeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HyperionSmokeEntities.csdl|res://*/HyperionSmokeEntities.ssdl|res://*/HyperionSmokeEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\Databases\HyperionSmoke.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

I am at a complete loss, PLEASE Help!

Comment: This SO post should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [blogpost](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/) there is a complete troubleshooting for this kind of problem.