# Unable to load the specified metadata resource MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my error when I'm inserting a record to database using MVC 4 and entity framework.

this is my codes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(Users u)
{

    SystemUser su = new SystemUser()
    {
        Username = u.Username,
        Password = u.Password,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        MiddleName = u.MiddleName,
        TerminalAccess = Convert.ToByte(u.TerminalAccess),
        MPassAccess = u.MPassAccess,
        CreationDate = u.DateCreation,
        ApplicationName = u.ApplicationName,
        Email = u.Email,
        IsApproved = u.isApproved

    };

    db.SystemUsers.Add(su);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

is there problem with my code or just the entity itself have a problem? 
please help.
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the application is unable to load the EDMX.

Use [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)