# Multiple EF6 DB Models with same Entity names conflicting and getting overwritten, How to set model output directory in EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, t4, ef-database-first

I am working with `EF6` and generating models (database-first) from multiple databases. Some databases have same table names so when model is generated they start conflicting. To solve `namespace` problem I went to `Model.tt` file properties in Solution Explorer and changed `Custom Tool Namespace` [image]

However this solved my problem only partially as when generating additional Models duplicate (same table name) `.cs` files are still being placed into project directory and same table name entities get overwritten.

**How do I set model output directory in EF6? Or solve this some other way?**

**EDIT:** After moving `.edmx` to it's own folder I am now getting `{"Unable to load the specified metadata resource."}` when accessing metadata on line `var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Ecom).ObjectContext;`

Comment: Place each EDMX in its own directory?

Comment: And maybe pull the model.tt's from the edmx's and place the different models in each directory-namespace-project. For every edmx you can pull the model.tt and place in what project or namespace you like, as long as you remember to state the relevant edmx file placement in the top of the model.tt file.

Comment: @CodeCaster Hi CodeCaster, Thanks for the answer, when I do this it blows up when doing reflection. I am using it to determine which entity belongs to which model. (I have quite a few models and a LOT of entities so this mechanism is essential or we are talking system rewrite) Blows up with `{"Unable to load the specified metadata resource."}` on `var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Ecom).ObjectContext;` line. It get's entities correctly though

Comment: @CodeCaster :) What if I go quantum?

Comment: @CodeCaster others are getting same problem and there is no answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514844/entity-framework-6-error-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource I am sure it has to do with dir name being cached or stored somewhere like GAC, it is still a progress. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CodeCaster

1. Create physical folder in your project directory
2. Add it to your project by including in `Solution Explorer`

[image]

3. Add model in that directory (I copied it over but you could try to just generate new one)
4. Change `.tt` file `Custom Tool Namespace`
   [image]
5. Check in `Web.config`/(`app.config`) if EF connection string generated has it's metadata set as following (Directory structure is done with `.`(dot) not `/`(slash)) like following **res://*/Ecom.Ecom.csdl*** (from being **res:///Ecom.csdl** while not in it's own folder).

Hope this saves some time.