# azure connection string format - adding in azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I am rebuilding a web app in Azure, I used to have all my app settings and connection strings in azure. So I have put the app settings back in, but the connection string for the Azure SQL server doesn't like what I am putting in.

In the web.config I have this

```
<add name="LeisureInsureEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LeisureModel.csdl|res://*/LeisureModel.ssdl|res://*/LeisureModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:leisureinsure.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=leisureinsure-website-preprod;persist security info=True;user id=XXXXXX;password=XXXXXX;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But I am having issues putting this into the value input field in azure.

[image]

Comment: Put the error in the question, not as a picture. It limits searchability...

Comment: its not an error, it shows where I am supposed to enter the connection string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149693/setting-ef-connection-string-in-azure-web-app

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the metadata information here. When I work with EF in Azure, I just use the connection string from the portal. e. g.:

```
data source=tcp:leisureinsure.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=leisureinsure-website-preprod;persist security info=True;user id=XXXXXX;password=XXXXXX;multipleactiveresultsets=True
```

Comment: Yea unfortunately im supposed to include all that metadata for EF. Thats what I have in web.config

Comment: The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149693/setting-ef-connection-string-in-azure-web-app