# Connection String asp.net webforms shared project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a entity framework edmx in a shared file which I am creating my db context with however when I have

```
<add name="UniteCmsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*
/DataModels.UniteCMSDB.csdl|res://*/DataModels.UniteCMSDB.ssdl|res:
//*/DataModels.UniteCMSDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
 connection string=&quot;data source=WIN-M71FFCH83PK\SQLFREELANCE28R2;   initial  catalog=openfire;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is the error I am getting

[Unable to load the specified metadata resource.]

> System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +599
>          System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +171
>          System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +63
>          System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths) +503
>          System.Data.Common.Utils.<>c__DisplayClass0.<Evaluate>b__1() +18
>          System.Data.Common.Utils.Result.GetValue() +130
>          System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg) +340
>          System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections) +301
>          System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection() +21
>          System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor) +163
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ConstructContext() +452
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +105
>          System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +17
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +175
>          Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformSelect() +16

In my web.config of my root project I have this which means i have the correct connection strings so i am at a total loss im using visual studio 2015 ef5.0 and sql server 2008 R2

```
<connectionStrings>

 <add name="UniteCmsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModels.UniteCMSDB.csdl|res://*/DataModels.UniteCMSDB.ssdl|res:   //*/DataModels.UniteCMSDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN-M71FFCH83PK\SQLFREELANCE28R2;initial catalog=openfire;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="UniteCmsEntitiesDal" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModels.UniteCmsModel.csdl|res://*/DataModels.UniteCmsModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModels.UniteCmsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN-M71FFCH83PK\SQLFREELANCE28R2;initial catalog=openfire;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Anybody have an idea of how to solve this?

Comment: try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource.

Comment: that didnt appeart to work i have that set to that but build action to entity deploy for the edmx

Comment: how about the section on model naming and troubleshooting from Craig Stuntz? http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/

Specifically, since your connection string is valid, is there an issue with your names not matching?

Comment: I have been throught that strange never had this issue in visual studio 2013

Comment: Did you verify all the naming matches?