# How to refactor web.config in an ASP.NET MVC4 Web App with EF5 and Database First approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, db-first

I started an ASP.NET MVC4 Web App with EF5 and the Db First approach. 
Now i´ve moved my Models and Context into a `MyApp.DataAccess` Class Library Project. I added a `MyApp.DataAccess` reference to `MyApp.Web`. What do I have to do with my `Web.config` and especially this section:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=..." />
    <add name="MyOldEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.OldDbModel.csdl|res://*/Models.OldDbModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.OldDbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=&quot;<MyDbServerIp, MyPort>&quot;;initial <LoginData>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'>" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**edit:**
error message: `Unable to load the specified metadata resource`

Comment: erm nothing? I use this approach in all projects, why do you think you need to change anything? Is something not working?

Comment: well, i started with all layers in one project. Now i moved my data stuff into a new class library project and generated a new DbContext. My added reference lets me access all my object but my <connectionstrings> settings are not working anymore. Can i generate a new web.config based on my new references or is it automatically updated when i add references? There might be also a namespace issue... ErrorMsg is `Unable to load the specified metadata resource`

Comment: You haven't actually included the full connection strings so its hard to tell whats wrong if I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13580577/1027919), i have to change

```
connectionString="metadata=...App=EntityFramework'"
```

to

```
connectionString="metadata=...application name=EntityFramework'"
```

Comment: I'd say that answer is wrong, you shouldn't even need an app.config the web.config should be used by the separate assembly.

Comment: i havent accepted an answer yet, so im up for other solutions. My edmx file was in `MyApp` and now is in `MyApp.DataAccess`. Btw this answer works.