# An unhandled exception of type System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException occurred in EntityFramework dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[Error Which i am facing ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLMGl.png) 
i don't know what happened suddenly, everything was working fine, now its giving me this error !
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EMSEntities dbobj = new EMSEntities();
    int employeesearch = Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text);

    int a = 0;

    var result = dbobj.sp_Employee_search(employeesearch).ToList();

    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        textBox1.Text = r.Emp_Name;
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(r.E_ID);
        textBox3.Text = r.City;
        textBox4.Text = r.Address;
        textBox5.Text = r.Gender;
        textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(r.Salary);
        textBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(r.D_ID);
        textBox8.Text = Convert.ToString(r.DG_ID);
        textBox9.Text = r.CNIC;
        textBox10.Text = r.Contact;
        textBox13.Text = Convert.ToString(r.DOJ);
        textBox12.Text = r.Age; 

        label11.Text = r.E_ID.ToString();
        a = r.E_ID;
    }
    if (a != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Employee Found");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Valid ID!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Was anything renamed, moved to another directory, or namespaces changed?

Comment: No i  did not changed anything , i just added publish tools from upgrade installation ..

Comment: In that case, I suspect the connection string was changed unintentionally. This error message is described in great detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource

Comment: i dont really dont understand what to do ..

Comment: Did you upgrade the project from a previous version of Visual Studio?