# System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException when deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, metadata

This post seems to be here a few more than a few times but I have gone through all of those and adjusted the code to have the true DLL name but still get the `Unable to load the specified metadata resource` error.

Now what comes the interesting part, this code works on the machine it was developed on in VS but does not work on any other machines or live version. I am not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Here is the Connection String - (Sources/Pass have been replaced with *)

```
<add name="RMUplistEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://RM.Data/DataEntities.Model1.csdl|res://RM.Data/DataEntities.Model1.ssdl|res://RM.Data/DataEntities.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*;initial catalog=RMUplist;user id=*;password=*;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is the stack trace

```
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderResource.LoadResource () [0x00016] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderResource.CreateReader () [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderResource.CreateReaders (System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace spaceToGet) [0x0001c] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderComposite.CreateReaders (System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace spaceToGet) [0x0001b] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadEdmItemCollection (System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader loader) [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache+<>c__DisplayClass5.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__0 (System.String k) [0x0000d] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) [0x00034] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs:1035 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace (System.String cacheKey, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader) [0x0000d] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions) [0x0001f] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace () [0x0000f] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection () [0x00014] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection, System.Boolean isConnectionConstructor, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator translator, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) [0x000ea] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection) [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel () [0x00006] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel () [0x00006] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext () [0x0007c] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize () [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType (System.Type entityType) [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].Initialize () [0x0000e] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].get_InternalContext () [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[TResult].System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider () [0x00016] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource] (System.Linq.IQueryable`1[T] source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate] predicate) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq.Queryable/src/System/Linq/Queryable.cs:39 
  at RM.UpList.Controllers.HomeController.DailyRotation (System.Nullable`1[T] date) [0x00099] in /*/RMUplist-master/RM.UpList/Controllers/HomeController.cs:109 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase,object[])
  at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase controller, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameters) [0x00072] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameters) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod () [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeDelegate`2[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+ActionInvocation,System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]:invoke_TResult_IAsyncResult_TState (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker/ActionInvocation)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`2[TResult,TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d () [0x00014] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters+<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f () [0x00086] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[TResult].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21+<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c () [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00041] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[TResult].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState innerState) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState]:invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.Controller/ExecuteCoreState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState innerState) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState]:invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler/ProcessRequestState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.async_handler_complete_cb (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:988
```

Comment: Could there be a conflict between .NET versions in the project and referenced DLL? Could the non local machines that will not run the program be missing the required .NET version?

Comment: They are the same, it also gives a 500 internal server error when hosted on Azure.

Comment: Where is your `Culture` and `PublicKeyToken` in connection string?

Comment: In the App.Config
    `<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />`
`

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if you have the EDMX in one project and you are using it from another project and the later in not able to load the EDMX files.

Have you tried changing your conenctionstring to

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/;
```

There are also a lot of other possible causes for this. You can google around. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource) has a lot of possible solutions.

Comment: That post is why I changed it to RM.Data from * in the connection string, still gives the error with *.